# Why is this program causing a runtime error?

Tags: java, unsupported-class-version

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Boolean expr = true;
        if (expr)
        {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
the error is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Comment: sorry but if you dont take the time to format this we dont want to take the time to answer it

Comment: You are missing a curly bracket?

Comment: There is no runtime error, only two syntax error and a typo. What error, anyway? Describe it if you want us to help.

Comment: You need to close `class Tes` wih `}` at the end of the code, plus I think you meant to name the class as `Test` with `Tes` but missed a `t` like I missed a `t` in the first `with` of my sentence.My missing `t` is not important but yours will be.

Answer (score 4):

`Static` should be with lower case: `static`.

Comment: :yeah sry actually that is my typing mistake.still it is giving runtime error why?

Answer (score 2):

Check this link

[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: why is it thrown & how to resolve?](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2009/01/javalangunsupportedclassversionerror.html)

> How to resolve UnsupportedClassVersionError?
>
> Whenever you encounter this error, do check if you’re using an earlier
>   version of JVM to execute the class file than the corresponding
>   version of compiler you used to compile the source code. The example
>   shown here was compiled using Java 5.0 compiler, but when I tried to
>   run using JVM 1.4, I got the above error. I just needed to switch
>   either to a JVM version 5.0 or above OR needed to switch to a Java
>   Compiler of JDK 1.4 or below (you of course need to make sure the
>   source code is compatible with the corresponding version of the
>   compiler otherwise you’ll start getting other compiler errors).
>
> A higher JVM version doesn’t cause a problem in most of cases unless
>   the class file format is quite old (and hence doesn’t lie in the
>   supported range as specified by Sun for that particular JVM version
>   ... as discussed above). But, it’s always a good practice to have both
>   the Compiler and the JVM of the same version.

Comment: where should i check the JVM version?

Comment: type `java -version` on terminal window. [How to check the JVM available on a computer ?](http://www.korilog.com/index.php/How-to-check-the-JVM-available-on-a-computer.html)

Comment: i checked JVM in lib folder of JDk

Answer (score 1):

This is no runtime error.  This doesn't compile.

Use `static` (lowercase s) instead of `Static`.

Comment: Some IDE's still create a .class even if there are compile errors in the code. The error part is substituted by an Exception.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I feel that labeling it as a compilation issue is more appropriate here.  At least it was, question has been changed in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

static should be lower case, and I believe you need it to be a public class. Also why are you using Boolean instead of boolean, wrapper types aren't necessary here.

Comment: she is new obviously, I used `String` not `string` when I started C# because I didn't know there is a `string` besides `String`.

Comment: static is in lowercase..actually that is my typing mistake,why it is giving runtime error

Comment: I did the same but types are usually lower case.

Comment: what is the runtime error then you're not giving us any information?

Comment: I believe it should be public class Test in a file called Test.java if not you will get a runtime error, everything else is valid

Comment: @krishna Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine attempts to read a class file and determines that the major and minor version numbers in the file are not supported.

Comment: @johnny:yeah that is the exact runtime error am getting.......why its is giving that error?

Comment: @krishna Are you sure you don't have a second JDK installed?

Comment: @johnny:yeah i am sure i dont have.......all my programs are running successfully..only this progarm giving the runtimr error...

Comment: @krishna please check my answer i am getting _Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?_ from SO.

Comment: @johnny:my JDK version is 1.5,and JVM also 1.5,why i am getting this error?

Comment: what IDE are you using to run this? try compiling and running from the command line with javac Test.java then java Test

Answer (score 1):

This code (if using JDK 5 and upwards, because of autoboxing/unboxing) runs perfectly without any `RuntimeException` and it will display `true` on the console.

Comment: @krishna bhargavi, is the the **full** code or did you just paste partial code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are compiling with one version of java and running with another. To be clearer you are compiling with a later version of java and running with an earlier version.

Are you compiling and running this class in an IDE?